# Implementation of type "long double" with GCC and C++11

Tags: c++, double

I've tried searching for information on long double, and so far I understand it is implemented differently by compilers.

When using GCC on Ubuntu (XUbuntu) Linux 12.10 I get this:

```
double PId = acos(-1);
long double PIl = acos(-1);
std::cout.precision(100);

std::cout << "PId " << sizeof(double) << " : " << PId << std::endl;
std::cout << "PIl " << sizeof(long double)  << " : " << PIl << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
PId 8  : 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
PIl 16 : 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

Anyone understand why they output (almost) the same thing?

Comment: `acos` won't return a long double as long as you don't pass a long double as argument..

Comment: Side note: g++-4.6.3 requires the use of `std::acos` instead of `acos` to show a difference (at least on my ubuntu x86 machine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the correct number of significant digits use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).  In C++11 we have [`digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) for decimal significant digits (as opposed to [`digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) which gives significant *bits*).

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int
main()
{
  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10);
  double PIf = acos(-1.0F);
  std::cout << "PIf " << sizeof(float) << " :  " << PIf << std::endl;

  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
  double PId = acos(-1.0);
  std::cout << "PId " << sizeof(double) << " :  " << PId << std::endl;

  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10);
  long double PIl = std::acos(-1.0L);
  std::cout << "PIl " << sizeof(long double)  << " : " << PIl << std::endl;
}
```

On x86_64 linux I get:

```
PIf 4 :  3.14159
PId 8 :  3.14159265358979
PIl 16 : 3.14159265358979324
```

Comment: It needs to use `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 + 1`. E.g. `std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::digits10 + 1 == 3`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin C++11 adds `std::numeric_limits<Tp>::digits10` that is guaranteed to round trip.  In g++ this is routed to `__glibcxx_max_digits(__FLT_MANT_DIG__)` where the arg is a macro gotten from configuration.  The result is digits10 + 2 for floating point types.  For integral types `max_digits10` is set to 0 (why?).  For the above code I should edit to `max_digits10`.  Also, digits10 has always been there - i.e. before C++11.

Comment: I'm going to look further about the integral versions of digits10 and max_digits10.  I wonder if either g++ of the standard is making a mistake.

Comment: I could argue that, for *display* purposes, `digits10` is correct.  The extra digits provided by using `max_digits10` are inaccurate but are necessary to ensure that enough bits are loaded after a read so that rewriting the decimal to `digits10` still retains accuracy.  Still not sure what's up with integral types.

Comment: The standard is pretty clear on [`digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10): _is the number of base-10 digits that can be represented by the type T without change, that is, any number with this many decimal digits can be converted to a value of type T and back to decimal form, without change due to rounding or overflow._ E.g. any 3 digits cannot be represented by `uint8_t`, whereas any 2 can.

Comment: I think they punted on `max_digits10` for integers.  They should have made it `max_digits10 = digits10 + 1` so that a large uint8_t of, say, 145 could be written and read back.  I think a lot of this had to do with mixing the semantics of integer and floating point in the same utility.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [reference of acos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/acos/), it will return a `long double` only if you pass a `long double` to it. You'll also have to use `std::acos` like baboon suggested. This works for me:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  double PId = acos((double)-1);
  long double PIl = std::acos(-1.0l);
  std::cout.precision(100);

  std::cout << "PId " << sizeof(double) << " :  " << PId << std::endl;
  std::cout << "PIl " << sizeof(long double)  << " : " << PIl << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
PId 8  : 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
PIl 12 : 3.14159265358979323851280895940618620443274267017841339111328125

         3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459
```

The last line is not part of the output and contains the correct digits for pi to this precision.

Comment: Use std::acos, as suggested by @bamboon. Then 1.0l works fine.

Comment: Not for MinGW, it seems: `error: 'acos' is not a member of 'std'`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
long double PIl = std::acos(-1.0L);
```

That makes you pass a long double and not just an int which gets converted.

Note that mostly all of these numbers are rubbish anyway. 
With an 8 byte double you get 15 Numbers of precision, if you compare your numbers with the real PI

```
3.1415926535897932384626433
```

You see that only the first 15 Numbers fit.

As noted in the comments, you probably won't get double the precision as the implementation might only use a 80Bit representation and then it depends on how many bits it reserves for the mantissa.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you I get a few extra characters printed. (13 more)

Is this expected? I would have thought I should get something about twice the length printed out?

Comment: @EdwardBird No, that totally depends on how many bit the implementation will reserve for the mantissa.